# How to check if std::cin has failed

Tags: c++, cin

I am making a game and at the start, the player needs to assign points to different categories of their character (like Fallout's [SPECIAL](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/SPECIAL)). Player input is currently read using `std::cin`. If the player inputs a letter instead of a number, `std::cin` will fail and crash the entire game.

I have attempted to check for failure with `std::cin.fail()` but no luck.

The relevant code which reads player input can be found below:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    switch(i) {
      case 0:
        cout <<"\n\nStrength (How strong you are)";
        cout <<"\nHow many points (you have " << total_SKILL_points << " left): ";
        std::cin >>Strength;
        if(std::cin.fail()) {
          std::cin.clear();
          cout <<"\n\nPlease enter a number!";
          i--;
          break;
        }
        total_SKILL_points = total_SKILL_points - Strength;
        break;
// keeps going, that's why no closing } for switch or for loop.
```

Is there any proper way to check if a letter has been passed to `std::cin`?

Comment: Using `std::cin.fail()` doesn't work in your case because the stream itself is not in an error state. `std::cin  >> Strength` has stopped reading because of invalid input and left the invalid input in the stream to be encountered on the next read operation - but it does NOT put the stream itself in an error state.  Instead of using `std::cin >> Strength`, read a line of input using `std::getline(std::cin, astring)` where `astring` is of type `std::string` and parse the string to check if it has required input or other data. Note: don't mix use of `std::getline()` with `>>` on the same stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the error flags and ignore the rest of the line if you get bad input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <list>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int total_SKILL_points = 100;
    int Strength;

    while(true) {
        std::cout << "\n\nStrength (How strong you are)\n"
                     "How many points (you have " << total_SKILL_points << " left): ";
        if(std::cin >> Strength) { // check that cin is in a good state after extraction
            // success
            break;
        } else {
            // failure
            if(std::cin.eof()) {
                std::cout << "user aborted\n";
                return 1;
            }

            std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter a number!";

            // clear error flags
            std::cin.clear();

            // ignore rest of line
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
    std::cout << Strength << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think try and catch is a good option here. You could do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

  switch(i){

    case 0:

      std::cout <<"\n\nStrength (How strong you are)";
      std::cout <<"\nHow many points (you have " << total_SKILL_points << " left): ";
      std::cin >>Strength;

      int intStrength;

      try{
        intStrength = std::stoi(Strength);
      }

      catch(std::invalid_argument const &e){
        std::cout <<"\n\nPlease enter a number!" << std::endl;
        i--;
        break;
      }

      total_SKILL_points = total_SKILL_points - intStrength;

      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the method that Peter gave. Thanks for the help.

Peter's answer for those skimming this post:

Using `std::cin.fail()` doesn't work in your case because the stream itself is not in an error state. `std::cin >> Strength` has stopped reading because of invalid input and left the invalid input in the stream to be encountered on the next read operation - but it does NOT put the stream itself in an error state. Instead of using `std::cin >> Strength`, read a line of input using

`std::getline(std::cin, astring)`

where a string is of type `std::string` and parse the string to check if it has required input or other data.

Note: don't mix use of `std::getline()` with `>>` on the same stream.