# Skipping a certain part of a longer input (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm a complete beginner to C++ and I'm doing a course at a university. We've gotten a lot of assignments to get the basics, and this is one that I'm absolutely stuck on. It's supposed to be the following.

> Input four integers: (where the user enters four integers).
> You entered the numbers: (what the user entered).

It works fine if users actually enter integers. The problems is that we're supposed to foolproof it too, so the user should be able to enter (for example) `1 2 7.5 3 ...` and also to add letters/text at the end.

I've solved the text bit (I figured that's just a `cin.ignore`). But I don't quite know how to make it so that it ignores possible decimals somewhere in the middle.

We have to use the `int` data type, and we can only use one. We can't use any control statements, either.

As stated above, I solved the issue with text (or a decimal) at the end, since the `cin.ignore` takes care of that. It works as expected. But for how to solve the middle part, I'm really quite dumbfounded.

My code right now looks like this (and does obviously not solve if the user puts something with decimals as one of the first three numbers):

```cpp
cout << "Enter four integers: ";
cin >> integer;
cout << "You entered the numbers: " << integer;
cin >> integer;
cout <<  " " << integer;
cin >> integer;
cout << " " << integer;
cin >> integer;
cout << " " << integer << "\n \n";
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
```

Comment: Check if [std::cin has failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925418/how-to-check-if-stdcin-has-failed) or have a look at [std::stoi[(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which can convert to string to integers and throw exceptions if input is wrong.

Comment: Best approach is to read in each input value as a `std::string` first and check/sanitize it before using it. If that is not an option, then you can use `cin.peek()` to check if the next character is whitespace after `>>` successfully reads in an `int` value, and if not then discard it

Comment: @RemyLebeau But how do they use that without control statements? I agree that's still the best answer though.

Comment: Fool-proofing pretty much requires control statements. It's hard to test whether or not the user input the correct data in the correct format (or successfully input data at all) without an conditional or two. I'd ask the instructor for clarification.

Comment: _"We can't use any control statements, either"_ - How will you then know if you've successfully extracted an `int` from `std::cin`? It seems like a very odd restriction to have in a C++ program.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting numbers from a stream is not too difficult once you get the hang of it. There are just a couple of idioms that you have to master.

Every input operation must be checked. Did `cin` fail? When an attempt to input an integer fails, perhaps because non-numeric characters were encountered, `cin` is placed in a failed state.

You can check its state by calling a one of these functions that return a `bool`:

1. `std::cin.fail()`
2. `std::cin.good()`

If `std::cin` is in a failed state, all subsequent input operations with it will fail, until you call `std::cin.clear()` to clear the three [iostate bits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate): `badbit`, `failbit`, and `eofbit`. Typically, you call `cin.clear()` to reset the stream, and then call `std::cin.ignore` to get rid of the bad inputs.

You can extract a number, and test for success at the same time. The following if-statement shows how. More often than not, this if-statement appears in a loop, along with appropriate prompts that are displayed with `std::cout`. You loop until the user either gets it right, or else cancels the input operation (and maybe a whole lot more).

```cpp
int n;
if (std::cin >> n)  // cin implicitly converted to 
{                   // result of `std::cin.good()`
    // success ...
}
else
{
    // failure ...
    std::cin.clear();  // clear `badbit`, `failbit`, and `eofbit`
    std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
}
```

Here is a complete program that demonstrates the idiom:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    if (std::cin >> n)  // cin implicitly converted to 
    {                   // result of `std::cin.good()`
        // success ...
        std::cout << "You entered: " << n << ".\n";
    }
    else
    {
        // failure ...
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        std::cout << "Invalid entry.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

###### An alternative using `getline`

In practice, I do not use the method described above.

I generally use `std::getline` for all input from `std::cin`. That reads a line at a time, and stores the result in a `std::string`.

After reading a line, you can then load it into a `std::stringstream`, and parse it from there. Alternatively, you can parse the line using functions such as `std::stoi`.

In my "toolbox", I have a function template named `tbx::get_number` that can be instantiated with `int`, `double`, or any other arithmetic type. I would be happy to share it, but the complete code comprises a suite of functions that total something like 350 lines. That's too much even for one of my bloated StackOverflow answers!

Here are a couple of the declarations it uses. Both functions return `true` when input succeeds, and `false` when the user cancels. The second one also performs range checking. The parameter `n` is an "output parameter" that holds the number that was entered by the user.

```cpp
    template< typename NumType >
        requires tbx::is_char_short_int_long_v<NumType>
            || std::is_floating_point_v<NumType>
    bool get_number(
        NumType& n
        , std::string const& prompt = "Enter value (press Enter to cancel): "
        , std::string const& reenter_prompt = "Invalid entry. Please reenter."
        , std::istream& ist = std::cin
        , std::ostream& ost = std::cout);

    template< typename NumType >
        requires tbx::is_char_short_int_long_v<NumType>
            || std::is_floating_point_v<NumType>
    bool get_number(
        NumType & n
        , NumType const min
        , NumType const max
        , std::string const& prompt = "Enter value (press Enter to cancel): "
        , std::string const& reenter_prompt = "Invalid entry. Please reenter."
        , std::istream & ist = std::cin
        , std::ostream & ost = std::cout);
```

As a student, I recommend that you try to write something like this, but perhaps without all the template mumbo-jumbo. Its a function that you might use in every homework assignment for the rest of the course.

Take a crack at:

```cpp
    bool get_int(
        int& n
        , std::string const& prompt = "Enter value (press Enter to cancel): "
        , std::string const& reenter_prompt = "Invalid entry. Please reenter."
        , std::istream& ist = std::cin
        , std::ostream& ost = std::cout);
```

Comment: TL;DR: 1) Read user input using [std::getline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), 2) Parse the input a line at a time.  3) "Parsing input" includes a) reading the numbers, b) detecting and handling "invalid data" (e.g. text), and c) Checking for too many/too few inputs.